# Почему программа пропускает строку? в Java

Tags: java

Почему программа перескакивает с имени на фамилию при втором вводе?

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    String[] name = new String[10];
    String[] lname = new String[10];
    String[] group = new String[10];
    Integer[] year = new Integer[10];

        while(i<=9) {

                System.out.println("Enter Name"+i);
                name[i] = scanner.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Last Name");
                lname[i] = scanner.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Group");
                group[i] = scanner.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Year");

                    year[i] = scanner.nextInt();



            i++;
            }
```

Вывод:

```
Enter Name0
Alex
Enter Last Name
Vrezub
Enter Group
i501
Enter Year
2001
Enter Name1
Enter Last Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `nextInt` не считывает конец строки.

```
  ...
  System.out.println("Enter Year");
  year[i] = scanner.nextInt();
  scanner.nextLine();

  i++;
}
```