# Компилятор пропускает String переменная = scanner.nextLine() - Java

Tags: java

```
    public void dodawanieStudentow() {
        int liczba = 1;
        String student = "studentu";
        int iloscStudentow = 0;
        float srednia;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Podaj ilosc studentow, ktorych chcesz utworzyc: ");
        iloscStudentow = scanner.nextInt();
        studenci = new String[iloscStudentow];
        System.out.println("Dodawanie nowych studentow: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < studenci.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Informacja o " + student + liczba + ": ");
            System.out.print("Podaj nazwisko: ");
            nazwisko = scanner.nextLine();
            if (nazwisko.length() < 3)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nazwisko musi miec minimum 3 znaki");
            try {
                System.out.print("Podaj wiek: ");
                wiek = scanner.nextInt();
                if (wiek < 17 || wiek > 80)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Podaj wiek w zakresie [17, 80]");
                System.out.print("Podaj ocene1: ");
                ocena1 = scanner.nextFloat();
                if (ocena1 < 2 || ocena1 > 5)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ocena musi byc w zakresie [2, 5]");
                System.out.print("Podaj ocene2: ");
                ocena2 = scanner.nextFloat();
                if (ocena1 < 2 || ocena1 > 5)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Ocena musi byc w zakresie [2, 5]");
            } catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
                System.out.print("Podales literke, musisz podac liczbe");
            }
            srednia = srednia();
            studenci[i] = "Dane o " + student + liczba + ": nazwisko: " + nazwisko + ", wiek: " + wiek + "" +
                    ", ocena1: " + ocena1 + ", ocena2: " + ocena2 + ", srednia: " + srednia;
            liczba++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < studenci.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(studenci[i]);
        }
    }
```

Как я проверяю переменную `nazwisko` на длину в строчке

```
            if (nazwisko.length() < 3)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nazwisko musi miec minimum 3 znaki");
```

То у меня выбивает эта ошибка, то есть мне даже компилятор не дает ввести данные в переменную
`nazwisko` в этой строчке `nazwisko = scanner.nextLine();`
Кто нибудь знает в чем проблема?

Comment: ничего оне не пропускает. nexLine() не для того, чтобы вводить данные

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему программа пропускает строку? в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/983344/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-java)

Comment: @Эникейщик а как мне вводить строку тогда? хаха, может с помощью nextInt()?

Comment: ок, я немного не точно написал. А со своим хаха пройдите в вопрос по ссылке. Там все написано. Как раз такой же случай. Один в один

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понимаю, что проблемы со сканером тоже надо решать, но при этом не стоит забывать о самых фундаментальных принципах, используемых разработчиками: на чиная от ооп, заканчивая solid, grasp и итд. Вы нарушаете все, что только можно. Какой смысл в этом коде? От реальной разработки эта задача далека, а в качестве учебного примера ничему хорошему она не научит. И еще... Именуйте свои переменные нормально, это ультимативное требование для разработчика любого уровня.
Попробуйте хотя бы так (остальной функционал пишите в другом классе):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class UserInputService {

    private final static Scanner SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static Student[] input() {
        Student[] studenci = new Student[input(Integer::valueOf, "Podaj ilosc studentow, ktorych chcesz utworzyc: ")];
        System.out.println("Dodawanie nowych studentow: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < studenci.length; i++) {
            studenci[i] = new Student();
            studenci[i].setNazwisko(input(s -> s, "Informacja o studentu " + i+1 + ": \r\nPodaj nazwisko: ",
                    var->var.length() < 3, "Nazwisko musi miec minimum 3 znaki"));
            studenci[i].setWiek(input(Integer::valueOf, "Podaj wiek: ", var->var < 17 || var > 80, "Podaj wiek w zakresie [17, 80]"));
            studenci[i].setOcena1(input(Float::valueOf, "Podaj ocene1: ", var->var < 2 || var > 5, "Ocena musi byc w zakresie [2, 5]"));
            studenci[i].setOcena2(input(Float::valueOf, "Podaj ocene2: ", (var)->var < 2 || var > 5, "Ocena musi byc w zakresie [2, 5]"));
        }
        return studenci;
    }
    
    private static <T> T input(Function<String, T> function, String message) {
        System.out.print(message);
        try {
            return function.apply(SCANNER.nextLine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return input(function, "Podales literke, musisz podac liczbe: ");
        }
    }
    
    private static <T> T input(Function<String, T> function, String message, Predicate<T> predicate, String errorMessage) {
        T result = input(function, message);
        if (predicate.test(result)) throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage);
        return result;
    }
    
}

class Student{
    private String nazwisko;
    private Integer wiek;
    private Float ocena1;
    private Float ocena2;

    public void setNazwisko(String nazwisko) {
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
    }

    public void setWiek(Integer wiek) {
        this.wiek = wiek;
    }

    public void setOcena1(Float ocena1) {
        this.ocena1 = ocena1;
    }

    public void setOcena2(Float ocena2) {
        this.ocena2 = ocena2;
    }

    public String getNazwisko() {
        return nazwisko;
    }

    public Integer getWiek() {
        return wiek;
    }

    public Float getOcena1() {
        return ocena1;
    }

    public Float getOcena2() {
        return ocena2;
    }
    
}
```